# Adding animation to arrow appears to change the element's central point

Tags: html, css, animation

I got an arrow in a banner section of my site which is supposed to be centered.
However, as soon as I add the bounce effect to it the central point of the element appears to change so its left side is centered instead of the element's center. I've been searching for an answer for this but haven't found anyone who has had the same issue. How could I fix this?

The arrow:

```
<div id="banner">
    <img src="<?php echo get_field('arrow_icon', $homepage); ?>" id="site-banner__arrow">
</div>
```

The bounce animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
    40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(4%);
    transform: translateY(4%);
  }
    60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(60%);
    transform: translateY(60%);
  }
}
```

The css for the arrow:

```
#site-banner__arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10%);
  -ms-transform:     translateY(-10%);
  transform:         translateY(-10%);
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform:     translateX(-50%);
  transform:         translateX(-50%);
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1.5s infinite;
  -moz-animation:    bounce 1.5s infinite;
  -o-animation:      bounce 1.5s infinite;
  animation:         bounce 1.5s infinite;

  &:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state:    paused;
    -o-animation-play-state:      paused;
    animation-play-state:         paused;
  }
}
```

Comment: When you have multiple transform directives, only the last one will be applied. It's like any other CSS attribute.

Comment: @Pepo_rasta Why don't you post that as an answer. Answers with a clear explanation of the problem as well a solution are usually the best.

Comment: not sure if it solve the problem, its just hint

Comment: @Pepo_rasta I don't see how that would cause the arrow to be moved slightly? Considering its left side is still in the actual center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pepo_rasta has stated your multiple transform statements are overriding one another.

This includes the animation so the answer is to make sure you keep all the transforms together is single statements.

```css
.center {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  background: red;
}
#site-banner__arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -10%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -10%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -10%);
  left: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1.5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: bounce 1.5s infinite;
  -o-animation: bounce 1.5s infinite;
  animation: bounce 1.5s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 4%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 4%);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 60%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 60%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-75-75-1.jpg" id="site-banner__arrow" />
</div>

<div class="center"></div>
```

It should be noted that this makes the code somewhat easier to write and read than multiple statements since this

```
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -10%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -10%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -10%);
```

could also be written as

```
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-10%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-10%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-10%);
```

I also seem to recall that Safari may have (have had?) issues with separated `transform` statements.